# How to obtain commit list between tags with JGit?

Tags: java, jgit

Suppose that given two tags as input, like "v5.8.0.202005061305-m2" and "v5.7.0.202003090808-r".

Is there a way to obtain the commit list between two tags with JGit?

I know GitHub has that functionality as you can compare two tags and see all the commits in between but can we do the same with JGit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LogCommand` has an `addRange` method to specify the commits you are interested in.

This is an example that resolves the tag names to commit IDs and then uses the `LogCommand` to list all commits in that range.

```java
Git git = ...
Ref tag1 = git.getRepository().exactRef("refs/tags/tag1");
Ref tag2 = git.getRepository().exactRef("refs/tags/tag2");
Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().addRange(tag1.getPeeledObjectId(), tag2.getPeeledObjectId());
for(RevCommit : commits ) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response ! Unfortunately however, it gives exception "Object 8fde51c82c6e671c9e68ba546f48c62b44a4175b is not a commit." at the 3rd line.

Comment: Nvm it is fixed when I changed "tag1.getObjectId()" to "tag1.getPeeledObjectId".

Comment: Good point, for annotated tags, `getObjectId` isn't enough. I've updated the answer.